# How to enter text into a new line while writing to a file?

Tags: python

Whenever I execute this piece of code more than once, my data is stored, but not in separate lines every time the user inputs a new data.

I have already tried to use `"/n"`, but in lieu of a new line, the command `"/n"` itself gets written to my file.

What can I do to enter the data in separate new lines?

```
file = open(f"{fileName}.txt", "a")
file.write("Text to write...")
file.close()
```

Comment: `\n` is for new line, not `/n`

Comment: use `\n` example: `file.write("\nyour text\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\n` and not `/n`, like so:

```py
file = open(f"{fileName}.txt", "a")
file.write("\nText to write...")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong slash, the correct one is 
So it is \n